# Creating group by group plots in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, facet-wrap

How do I use ggplot to create grouped plots of clusters, each with a few individuals within it.

For example:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "factor"), 
    cluster = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
    val = c(1.2581800436601, 6.79055672604591, 9.77732860250399, 
    3.60806297743693, 1.14399523707107, 7.9990872181952, 3.16242988454178, 
    5.64627967076376, 8.82345798192546, 4.29119206266478, 8.62997844815254, 
    6.46683012368158), date = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
    1, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))

   ID cluster      val date
1   1       1 1.258180    1
2   1       1 6.790557    2
3   2       1 9.777329    1
4   2       1 3.608063    2
5   3       2 1.143995    1
6   3       2 7.999087    2
7   4       2 3.162430    1
8   4       2 5.646280    2
9   5       3 8.823458    1
10  5       3 4.291192    2
11  6       3 8.629978    1
12  6       3 6.466830    2
```

I want to create 2x3 plot, with 3 columns of clusters, and 2 rows of plots in each column for each individual.

The current code I am using gives the general structure of the plot but there are many empty plots:

```
ggplot(df, aes(date,val)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + facet_grid(ID~cluster)
```

Comment: `facet_wrap(~ cluster + ID)`

Comment: @PoGibas: no, because then the first row will contain clusters/IDs 1/1, 1/2 and 2/3, and the second 2/4, 3/5 and 3/6.

Answer (score 0):

To group them by cluster you would have to impose the correct order in your data. Right now, `facet_wrap` takes it as it comes. One way is to rearrange the df, the other is to create a dummy variable (cluster + ID) and arrange the levels in the desired order.

So, you want the IDs 1, 3 and 5 in the top row, and IDs 2, 4 and 6 in the bottom row, is that correct? Here is one way:

```
df$ID <- factor(df$ID, levels=as.character(c(1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6)))
ggplot(df, aes(date,val)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') +  
  facet_wrap(~ID + cluster, ncol=3)
```

**Notes.**

1. Having a factor with numeric values is dangerous. In the above, I have reordered the factor levels. So now "3" (ID 3) has the factor level "3" and numeric value *2*. Since factor sometimes gets converted to strings, sometimes to its numeric values, this can lead in certain circumstances to mayhem. Also, on the facet wrap plot, you can't distinguish what number corresponds to the ID, and what to the cluster.

   My advice is to always use explicit IDs, for example

   ```
   df <- df %>% mutate(ID=paste0("ID.", ID), cluster=paste0("CL.", cluster))
   df$ID <- factor(df$ID, levels=paste0("ID.", (c(1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6))))
   ```
2. An alternative to the approach above would be to use `facet_grid` with a dummy variable:

   ```
   df$row <- factor(rep(rep(c("top", "bottom"), each=2), 3), 
                     levels=c("top", "bottom"))
   ggplot(df, aes(date,val)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
       facet_grid(rows=vars(row), cols=vars(cluster)) +
       theme(strip.text.y = element_blank())
   ```

[image]